# How to show the 2k video completly in imshow of opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to analysis a object tracking problem using DSST algorithm （Accurate Scale Estimation for RobustVisual Tracking）. However my testing video is 2k, and the imshow function can't show it clearly. Moreover, the structure of the code from github is fully-packaged... can't easily find the code to make any change.

I tried add the code

```
(
//cv::namedWindow(_windowTitle.c_str(), cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
//cv::resizeWindow(_windowTitle.c_str(),980,600);
)
```

above the `imshow`, but actually it doesn't working, just resize the windows but can't resize the video.

```
if (_paras.showOutput)
    {
        Mat hudImage;
        _image.copyTo(hudImage);
        rectangle(hudImage, _boundingBox, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
        Point_<double> center;
        center.x = _boundingBox.x + _boundingBox.width / 2;
        center.y = _boundingBox.y + _boundingBox.height / 2;
        circle(hudImage, center, 3, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);

        stringstream ss;
        ss << "FPS: " << fps;
        putText(hudImage, ss.str(), Point(20, 20), FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 0.5, Scalar(255, 0, 0));

        ss.str("");
        ss.clear();
        ss << "#" << _frameIdx;
        putText(hudImage, ss.str(), Point(hudImage.cols - 60, 20), FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 0.5, Scalar(255, 0, 0));

        if (_debug != 0)
            _debug->printOnImage(hudImage);

        if (!_targetOnFrame)
        {
            cv::Point_<double> tl = _boundingBox.tl();
            cv::Point_<double> br = _boundingBox.br();

            line(hudImage, tl, br, Scalar(0, 0, 255));
            line(hudImage, cv::Point_<double>(tl.x, br.y),
                cv::Point_<double>(br.x, tl.y), Scalar(0, 0, 255));
        }
        //cv::namedWindow(_windowTitle.c_str(), cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        //cv::resizeWindow(_windowTitle.c_str(),980,600);
        imshow(_windowTitle.c_str(), hudImage);

        if (!_paras.imgExportPath.empty())
        {
            stringstream ssi;
            ssi << setfill('0') << setw(5) << _frameIdx << ".png";
            std::string imgPath = _paras.imgExportPath + ssi.str();

            try
            {
                imwrite(imgPath, hudImage);
            }
            catch (runtime_error& runtimeError)
            {
                cerr << "Could not write output images: " << runtimeError.what() << endl;
            }
        }
}
```

I expect the output video showing completly so that I can chasing a right zone of it.

Comment: "can't show it clearly" -- Can you elaborate? | Setting `WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` means that "the user cannot resize the window, the size is constrainted by the image displayed". Hence, calling `resizeWindow` immediately after that isn't likely to accomplish much (not to mention that 980 x 600 seems a bit too small for "2k")